# When is it better to just work in one feature branch than creating multiple

Tags: svn, branch, feature-branch

**Background**

I received the task to search for redundant jquery selectors in our code. Now, the files where our JS code is located is seperated into different modules.

My supervisor gave me the task and told me that I should create a feature branch for each Module (sometimes it only contains 1 - 2 js files).

I'm struggling between doing it properly (like a programmer would) and being efficient without wasting to much time creating feature branches.

**Question**

Therefore my question: When should I create multiple feature branches and when only one to prevent an overkill?

Answer (score 0):

With some experience I have the following answer to my own question.

**Disclaimer:** This is primarily opinion based. Whether you agree or disagree is up to you.

Depending on how huge your project is you might wanna create multiple feature-branches to keep some separation. However if it's just a tiny project then I'd be fine if you implement it in one feature branch. As long as you make sure to keep some structure. I.e. resolve these .js-Files that belong to each other and don't touch others. Therefore your commits stay clean.